# Why does my ViewPager have children of zero width and height?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I'm making a ViewPager to display a series of images, which are identified by their position in an array of resource values.  Here is my `instantiateItem` code for the adapter:

```
//indexes the images
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0.getTag().equals(arg1);
}

//serves the views
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView view = new ImageView(container.getContext());
    view.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    view.setTag(position);
    view.setImageResource(mImages.get(position));
    container.addView(view, position);
    return view;
}
```

It doesn't display.  Looking at `container.getChildAt(0)` confirms that the layout parameters are set to `MATCH_PARENT` but the width and height are 0.  The container's own width and height are the screen dimensions (as expected).

Changing the code to

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView view = (ImageView) View.inflate(container.getContext(), R.layout.imageview, null);
    view.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    view.setTag(position);
    view.setImageResource(mImages.get(position));
    container.addView(view, position);
    return view;
}
```

(where `R.layout.imageview` is just a layout with an `ImageView` in) didn't work.  Setting the background colour to arbitrary visible values shows that the views are essentially not visible.  What's going on?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S3 on Jellybean, by the way.

Comment: did you solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object returned should not be the `View`, but the object used to *identify* the `View`.  In this case, the position is being used as an index, so the return value should be position:

```
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0.getTag().equals(arg1);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView view = new ImageView(container.getContext());
    view.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    view.setTag(position);
    view.setImageResource(mImages.get(position));
    container.addView(view, position);
    return position;
}
```